# Why does the IEnumerable returned by HttpRequestHeaders.GetValues(string) only ever have 1 string?

Tags: c#, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2

I can't figure out why the IEnumerable returned by the **HttpRequestHeaders.GetValues(string)** returns an IEnumerable that only ever has 1 item in it.

When multiple items with the requested name are in the header, I get an IEnumerable with 1 string entry that equals the CSV concatenation of all of the matching header items.

I would expect if the return value is an IEnumerable that each matching header entry would be its own item.  Conversely, if the method always concatenates everything, then I would expect the return value to just be a single string.

**Expected:**

```
{ "Test", "Test2" }
```

**Actual:**

```
{ "Test, Test2" }
```

Using Fiddler to test, I've tried adding multiple entries to my header:

```
GET https://localhost/api/v1/users/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
TestHeaderField: Test
TestHeaderField: Test2
```

As well as multiple comma separated items:

```
GET https://localhost/api/v1/users/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
TestHeaderField: Test, Test2
```

I'm using ASP.NET Web API 2 version 5.0.0, with .Net 4.5.1.  Is there something I'm missing here or is this a bug in the underlying code?

Comment: Simply because it's what RFC 2616 mandates. Explicitly from HTTP 1.1 §4.2: _"Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list"_. HttpRequestHeaders contains parsed headers and parser performs some "clean-up".

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti But the second example *is* a comma-separated list of values and `GetValues` returns an `IEnumerable`, so why wouldn't there be multiple values? Why wouldn't it just return a `string`?

Comment: @RGraham because 2nd example doesn't need any clean-up. A comma separated list...IS a single string. I wonder WHEN multiple values may be returned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpRequestHeaders.GetValues will return multiple values for headers it has parsers for, if the values are well-formed. You can test this by sending multiple `Accept` headers:

```
GET https://localhost/api/v1/users/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: text/html
Accept: application/xhtml+xml
Accept: application/xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to get each request header:

```
NameValueCollection headers = HttpRequestHeaders;
for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
{
    string key = headers.GetKey(i);
    string value = headers.Get(i);
    // use key and value
}
```

Tweak this as needed, you seem to only have values but not keys.